# How to Update/Append Model Name Column in Csv File with Respect to Another Column(Epoch) which has value 0

Tags: python, pandas, csv, lambda

I am writing model history in csv in which later on I am adding a new column model name where I need to update model name everytime when I run with timestamp.But currently what I am facing is that it is updating the model name not just for the latest one but for all wherever it finds Epoch value as 0.
Kindly Help if anybody have any idea.

Training CSV Contains the given data and model_na varible basically conatains FileName_Time stamp which you can see in model name column---

```html
epoch accuracy loss val_accuracy val_loss
0 0.5991348 0.954963956 0.61725134 0.928029025
1 0.6101555 0.934882281 0.61725134 0.926564478
2 0.6101555 0.933647258 0.61725134 0.925897177
3 0.6101555 0.933986878 0.61725134 0.925625712
4 0.6101555 0.93378263 0.61725134 0.92587147
5 0.6101555 0.933501081 0.61725134 0.925496578
6 0.6101555 0.934000334 0.61725134 0.925522646
7 0.6101555 0.933863895 0.61725134 0.926479578
8 0.6101555 0.933888928 0.61725134 0.926321284
0 0.59779584 0.954151712 0.61725134 0.925566993
1 0.6101555 0.935797452 0.61725134 0.926761304
2 0.6101555 0.935356209 0.61725134 0.926412033
3 0.6101555 0.933948885 0.61725134 0.925769904
0 0.6020188 0.956590114 0.61725134 0.928246004
1 0.6101555 0.935971673 0.61725134 0.925614129
2 0.6101555 0.934430503 0.61725134 0.926334595
3 0.6101555 0.933712303 0.61725134 0.927097352
4 0.6101555 0.933796334 0.61725134 0.925467268
5 0.6101555 0.93388608 0.61725134 0.925654634
6 0.6101555 0.933794685 0.61725134 0.925489133
7 0.6101555 0.933911282 0.61725134 0.926129941
```

I am using given code write now---
'''
df = pd.read_csv('\History\training.csv')

Type_new = pd.Series([])

for i in range(len(df)):

```
if df["epoch"][i] == 0: 

    Type_new[i]=model_na
```

df.insert(0, "Model_Name", Type_new)

df.to_csv('\History\cleaned_twitter_final.csv',index=False)

'''
Current Output----

```html
Model_Name epoch accuracy loss val_accuracy val_loss
LSTM_Model_19_Feb_2020_122031 0 0.5991348 0.954963956 0.61725134 0.928029025
 1 0.6101555 0.934882281 0.61725134 0.926564478
 2 0.6101555 0.933647258 0.61725134 0.925897177
 3 0.6101555 0.933986878 0.61725134 0.925625712
 4 0.6101555 0.93378263 0.61725134 0.92587147
 5 0.6101555 0.933501081 0.61725134 0.925496578
 6 0.6101555 0.934000334 0.61725134 0.925522646
 7 0.6101555 0.933863895 0.61725134 0.926479578
 8 0.6101555 0.933888928 0.61725134 0.926321284
LSTM_Model_19_Feb_2020_122031 0 0.59779584 0.954151712 0.61725134 0.925566993
 1 0.6101555 0.935797452 0.61725134 0.926761304
 2 0.6101555 0.935356209 0.61725134 0.926412033
 3 0.6101555 0.933948885 0.61725134 0.925769904
```

Expected Output---

```html
Model_Name epoch accuracy loss val_accuracy val_loss
LSTM_Model_19_Feb_2020_122031 0 0.5991348 0.954963956 0.61725134 0.928029025
 1 0.6101555 0.934882281 0.61725134 0.926564478
 2 0.6101555 0.933647258 0.61725134 0.925897177
 3 0.6101555 0.933986878 0.61725134 0.925625712
 4 0.6101555 0.93378263 0.61725134 0.92587147
 5 0.6101555 0.933501081 0.61725134 0.925496578
 6 0.6101555 0.934000334 0.61725134 0.925522646
 7 0.6101555 0.933863895 0.61725134 0.926479578
 8 0.6101555 0.933888928 0.61725134 0.926321284
LSTM_Model_19_Feb_2020_132031 0 0.59779584 0.954151712 0.61725134 0.925566993
 1 0.6101555 0.935797452 0.61725134 0.926761304
 2 0.6101555 0.935356209 0.61725134 0.926412033
 3 0.6101555 0.933948885 0.61725134 0.925769904
```

Comment: can you give a little more code its hard for me to tell what you are doing

Comment: @Ani you need to change every model name that has `epoch = 0`?

Comment: @MNM updated as requested....

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Yes only the latest one but old one should be as it is... no change.

Comment: @Ani based on what you set `Model_name`? It should by changed by what methods?

Comment: Where is model_na set? This is what you will have to change to change the name.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%d_%b_%Y_%H%M%S', t)
model_na = "LSTM_Model_" + timestamp

Comment: @MNM t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%d_%b_%Y_%H%M%S', t)
model_na = "LSTM_Model_" + timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution....
One can use csv logger...